# Display <ul class> above parent <div class> using z-index?

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

Example: http://betafreshmedia.com/nathan/coffee.html

When you click a category, I want the dropdown to appear ABOVE the rest of the categories. Right now everything is `position:relative` so they shift around to accomodate the `<ul>`.  I'd like to use `position:absolute` with a z-index, but can't seem to get it to work. Please note the javascript at the end of `<body>` has to correspond with whatever we decide to do.

Thanks!

Comment: If you set position of the 'coffeetype' class to have position absolute the drop down appears over the selected coffee.  Is this the behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the `z-index` off the trigger divs, and use `position: absolute` on the `ul` and it'll work. Only ever use `z-index` if you *have* to. If elements don't explicitly require `z-index`, don't set it.